# multiple Like expression in sql query using case exprssion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query written below.

```
SELECT T1.[AcctCode],T1.[Segment_0],SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]) AS BUDGET, SUM(T3.[Debit]) AS DEBIT,
       AcctName = CASE WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6001%%' THEN 'Operating Cost' 
                       WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6002%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
                       WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6003%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
                       WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6004%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
                       WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6005%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
                       WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6006%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
         ELSE T1.[AcctName] END
FROM OBGT T0 INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode]=T1.[AcctCode] INNER JOIN OBGS T2 
ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId] INNER JOIN JDT1 T3 ON T1.[AcctCode] = T3.[Account] INNER JOIN OASC T4 ON T1.[Project]=T4.[Code] 
where T1.[Segment_0] like '60%%'
GROUP BY T1.[AcctCode],T1.[Segment_0],T1.[AcctName]
```

This query gives me different values for operating cost. I need something like `WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6002%%,6003%%,6004%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'`. Is it possible? I don't need different likes by one by one. I need all in one as operating cost. Please help me out for this.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: In simple words the if segment_0 starts from 6 then account name should be operating cost. i am getting multiple rows as i put cases upto '6006'.  i need only one row. @GordonLinoff

Comment: Wait, what, are we really talking "starts with 6"? As in `LIKE '6%'` would suffice?

Comment: @Kirat You can try distinct - like select distinct ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `T1.[Segment_0]` are only numeric value you can use this syntax with `between`:

```
case when substring(T1.[Segment_0], 1, 4) between 6001 and 6006 then 'Operating Cost' else T1.[AcctName] end
```

Else you can use `IN` :

```
case when substring(T1.[Segment_0], 1, 4) in ('6001','6002','6003','6004','6005','6006') then 'Operating Cost' else T1.[AcctName] end
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you issue is that you are including `AcctName` in the `group by` rather than the result of the `case`.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
SELECT T1.[AcctCode],T1.[Segment_0],SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]) AS BUDGET, SUM(T3.[Debit]) AS DEBIT,
       AcctName = (CASE WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6001%%' THEN 'Operating Cost' 
                        WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6002%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
                        WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6003%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
                        WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6004%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
                        WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6005%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
                        WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6006%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
                   ELSE T1.[AcctName] END)
FROM OBGT T0 INNER JOIN OACT
     T1
     ON T0.[AcctCode]=T1.[AcctCode] INNER JOIN
     OBGS T2
     ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId] INNER JOIN
     JDT1 T3
     ON T1.[AcctCode] = T3.[Account] INNER JOIN
     OASC T4
     ON T1.[Project] = T4.[Code] 
where T1.[Segment_0] like '60%%'
GROUP BY T1.[AcctCode], T1.[Segment_0], 
         (CASE WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6001%%' THEN 'Operating Cost' 
               WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6002%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
               WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6003%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
               WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6004%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
               WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6005%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
               WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6006%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'
               ELSE T1.[AcctName]
          END);
```

EDIT:

You might also want to remove `Segment_0` from both the `select` and `group by`.  Without sample data, it is hard to tell.

Comment: i need   AcctName = (CASE WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '6001%% and 6002%%,6003%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'). i need this thing. rather than putting different LIKE i need one line result.  if segment_0 like 6002%%,6003%% then acctname should be operating cost

Comment: @Kirat . . . Putting the `case` in the `group by` *instead of* `ACCTNAME` should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server LIKE can do [pattern matching](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Try `CASE WHEN T1.[Segment_0] LIKE '600[123456]%%' THEN 'Operating Cost'`

Comment: +1. Not sure about keeping the `%%` from the original question, though. *Two* strings of zero or more characters?

Comment: with this i am still getting the same result.as i put in question